# Extracting JSON data Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working a Xamarin.Forms App that uses the Azure Face API. With this API you retrieve a JSON response (See Below).

I want to extract the gender of the person in the image but am having trouble with it as I am  very new to this.

I extract the full JSON response into a string but I would like to be able to extract data such as the 'Gender' or the 'Age' of the person in the image.

```
[{"faceId":"9448dfe4-afb6-4557-94fe-010fc439ff36","faceRectangle":{"top":635,"left":639,"width":789,"height":789},"faceAttributes":{"smile":0.187,"headPose":{"pitch":0.0,"roll":-1.6,"yaw":-7.9},"gender":"male","age":34.6,"facialHair":{"moustache":0.5,"beard":0.6,"sideburns":0.6},"glasses":"NoGlasses","emotion":{"anger":0.0,"contempt":0.69,"disgust":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":0.187,"neutral":0.12,"sadness":0.002,"surprise":0.0},"blur":{"blurLevel":"low","value":0.15},"exposure":{"exposureLevel":"overExposure","value":0.85},"noise":{"noiseLevel":"medium","value":0.42},"makeup":{"eyeMakeup":false,"lipMakeup":false},"accessories":[],"occlusion":{"foreheadOccluded":false,"eyeOccluded":false,"mouthOccluded":false},"hair":{"bald":0.02,"invisible":false,"hairColor":[{"color":"brown","confidence":1.0},{"color":"black","confidence":0.95},{"color":"other","confidence":0.22},{"color":"blond","confidence":0.11},{"color":"gray","confidence":0.05},{"color":"red","confidence":0.04}]}}}]
```

This is how I set the JSON data to a string.

```
 string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

You usually want to create a class that represents your response e. g. `Person`.  Then you could use the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) nuget package to deserialize the object.:

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(contentString);
```

Now you can access the values like:

```
person.Gender
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureFace>(contentString);
Debug.WriteLine(results.faceAttributes.age);
```

#### C# Model Used (via http://jsonutils.com)

```
public class FaceRectangle
{
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class HeadPose
{
    public double pitch { get; set; }
    public double roll { get; set; }
    public double yaw { get; set; }
}

public class FacialHair
{
    public double moustache { get; set; }
    public double beard { get; set; }
    public double sideburns { get; set; }
}

public class Emotion
{
    public double anger { get; set; }
    public double contempt { get; set; }
    public double disgust { get; set; }
    public double fear { get; set; }
    public double happiness { get; set; }
    public double neutral { get; set; }
    public double sadness { get; set; }
    public double surprise { get; set; }
}

public class Blur
{
    public string blurLevel { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public class Exposure
{
    public string exposureLevel { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public class Noise
{
    public string noiseLevel { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public class Makeup
{
    public bool eyeMakeup { get; set; }
    public bool lipMakeup { get; set; }
}

public class Occlusion
{
    public bool foreheadOccluded { get; set; }
    public bool eyeOccluded { get; set; }
    public bool mouthOccluded { get; set; }
}

public class HairColor
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public double confidence { get; set; }
}

public class Hair
{
    public double bald { get; set; }
    public bool invisible { get; set; }
    public IList<HairColor> hairColor { get; set; }
}

public class FaceAttributes
{
    public double smile { get; set; }
    public HeadPose headPose { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public double age { get; set; }
    public FacialHair facialHair { get; set; }
    public string glasses { get; set; }
    public Emotion emotion { get; set; }
    public Blur blur { get; set; }
    public Exposure exposure { get; set; }
    public Noise noise { get; set; }
    public Makeup makeup { get; set; }
    public IList<object> accessories { get; set; }
    public Occlusion occlusion { get; set; }
    public Hair hair { get; set; }
}

public class AzureFace 
{
    public string faceId { get; set; }
    public FaceRectangle faceRectangle { get; set; }
    public FaceAttributes faceAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fantastic response! I have another problem now where in the JSON response I have no array header value (EG: "employees": [{..........  )

Comment: @JohnDoe Not sure I understand, what is `employees` in relation to Azure Face API? I would recommend posting another question with the code/problem

Comment: thank you @sushihangover! I have updated the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750774/extracting-json-data-in-c-sharp